Maximum number of ones in a full rank matrix with a restriction
Consider  $n \times n$  binary matrices.  I am interested in the largest number of ones possible in an $n \times n$ binary matrix with full rank over the field of integers mod 2 with the following restriction.

No two rows have two or more bits set to 1 in common positions.

The following is an example of such a matrix.
[[1 0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 1 0]]

The optimal values for $n = 2, 3, 4, 5$ are $3, 5, 9, 11$.
[Cross-posted to mathoverflow.net]

For $n=5$, I can get 12. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \ 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 & 1 \ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0   \end{pmatrix}$.
For $n=6$, I can get 16. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \
\end{pmatrix}$. $\quad$ These were quite straightforward constructions, so please recheck. FWIW Random sampling doesn't seem like it will yield the optimal value.

For $n = 3$, we have 6: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \ 1 &  0 & 1 \ 0 & 1 & 1 \ \end{pmatrix}$. For $n=7$, the Fano plane construction yields 21. So $n = 8$ is at least 23 (add the last point, and any other).

Using the standard incidence matrix interpretation to count row pairs of 1-1,  I can show that $R_n \leq \lfloor  \frac{ \sqrt{ n^2 ( 4n-3) }  + n}{2} \rfloor $, which matches my values for $n \leq 7$. For $n = 8$, it yields 25, but I wasn't able to obtain 25 or 24, so 23 might be the best. $\quad$ This upper bound can be achieved for projective planes (like the Fano plane), so it might be the best that we can easily say.

@CalvinLin Your n =3  example doesn't have full rank over  mod 2.  Row 3 = row 2 + row 1

Ah, I missed the "full rank" condition. Didn't check it for the others either. EG For $n = 5$, row 1 + row 2 + row 4 + row 5 = 0

[This is incomplete.  It establishes an upper bound for the valu for "No two rows have two or more bits set to 1 in common positions". However, it ignores the full rank requirement, which has significant implications on the construction.]
Suppose there are $r_i$ 1's in row $i$.
Then, by counting row pairs of $1-1$ in the incidence matrix,

There are $ \sum { r_i \choose 2 } $ row pairs
The condition that "any 2 rows do not have 2 or more bits set to 1 in common position" means that the number of row pairs is at most ${ n \choose 2 }$.

Thus, $$ \sum { r_i \choose 2 } \leq { n \choose 2 }.$$
The goal is to determine $ R_n = \max \sum r_i$.
Since ${ x \choose 2 } $ is a convex function, applying Jensen's yields
$$n { \frac{ \sum r_i } { n} \choose 2 } \leq \sum { r_i \choose 2 }, $$
Viewing this as a quadratic in $\sum r_i$, we get $\sum r_i \leq \lfloor  \frac{ \sqrt{ n^2 ( 4n-3) }  + n}{2} \rfloor $, so this is an upper bound for $R_n$.
Note that this is a necessary, though not sufficient, condition. For us to say that  $R_n = \lfloor  \frac{ \sqrt{ n^2 ( 4n-3) }  + n}{2} \rfloor $, we need to find a construction for each $n$. I suspect that this is hard (though it's likely to have been studied, I'm just not familiar enough with the literature).
The initial values starting from $n =2$ are $\lfloor  \frac{ \sqrt{ n^2 ( 4n-3) }  + n}{2} \rfloor = 3, 6, 9, 12, 16, 21, 25, \ldots$.
